# Document access during initialisation issue on Android

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble accessing files saved in `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` on android only, I keep locale, theme and assets files stored there and when booting up the app those files are always inaccessible and as a result the app does not load, I tried using `shared_prefs` to track a first load scenario to use the files in `assets/` and then later use the ones download but that seems to be an unreliable fix as at 2nd run they also inaccessible.

The only thing that seems to work reliable is the theme.json, but both copy functions run through the same helpers so what copies the theme over is what copies the locale over. Theme is loaded up in main.dart but the locale is loaded up with `EasylocaLizationDelegate` and if the files are in Document storage it can never load them up.

None of these issues are present on iOS, does anyone know of any special tricks to make this work for android, I have tried google but not really sure what to search for.

```
class FileHelpers {
  static Future<Directory> getDownloadDirectory() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    globals.documentDirectory = dir;
    return dir;
  }

  static verifyOrCreateDirectory(String folderName) async {
    String path = globals.documentDirectory.path;
    final Directory _folder = Directory('$path/$folderName/');

    if (await _folder.exists()) {
      //if folder already exists return path
      return _folder.path;
    } else {
      //if folder not exists create folder and then return its path
      final Directory _createdFolder = await _folder.create(recursive: true);
      return _createdFolder.path;
    }
  }

  static void writeStringToFile(String data, String path) {
    new File(path).writeAsString(jsonEncode(data));
  }
}

class ThemeHelpers {
  static final _folderName = 'theme';
  static final _fileName = 'theme.json';

  static Future<void> loadTheme() async {
    String documentPath = globals.documentDirectory.path;

    try {
      String assetTheme = 'assets/$_fileName';
      String documentTheme = "$documentPath/$_folderName/$_fileName";
      String loadPath = documentTheme;

      /// We need to check if we can use the local assets as Android has some
      /// issues using document assets this early on in the app run
      if (!globals.canUseLocalAssets) {
        loadPath = assetTheme;
      }

      Box box = await Hive.openBox(globals.environment.entryCode);
      String data = await rootBundle.loadString(loadPath);

      box.put(HIVE_COLLECTION_THEME, data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  /// In order to support offline themes we ship the current version as at build
  /// time with the app.
  /// This method is to copy the files from the assets folder into the documents
  /// directory. This gives us the option to then update when needed.
  static copyTheme() async {
    String path = await FileHelpers.verifyOrCreateDirectory(_folderName);
    String themePath = '$path/$_fileName';

    /// Check if the file already exists, if not copy it over
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(themePath) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
      String assetPath = "assets/$_fileName";
      String data = await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);

      await new File(themePath).writeAsString(data);
      print('theme copied');
    }
  }

  static updateTheme() async {
    String path = await FileHelpers.verifyOrCreateDirectory(_folderName);

    var url = ApiEndpoint.uri('/theme').toString();

    try {
      bool shouldUpdate = await _checkIfUpdated();
      if (shouldUpdate) {
        /// If theme has been updated download the latest
        /// version and store it.
        ///
        /// Currently this happens as a non-blocking action
        /// so updates will take effect the next time the user opens the app.
        var response = await Session.apiGet(url);

        String localePath = '$path/$_fileName';
        await new File(localePath).writeAsString(jsonEncode(response));

        /// Once updated reload the theme into [Hive]
        loadTheme();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Unable to update theme');
    }
  }

  /// This method makes  alight call comparing the [__lastUpdated] in our local
  /// copy of the Locale to the API version.
  static Future<bool> _checkIfUpdated() async {
    String assetPath =
        '${globals.documentDirectory.path}/$_folderName/$_fileName';

    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(assetPath) ==
        FileSystemEntityType.notFound) throw "File not found";

    try {
      String data = await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);

      String currentThemeDate = json.decode(data)['__lastUpdated'];

      var url = ApiEndpoint.uri(
        '/theme/check',
        queryParameters: {
          "date": currentThemeDate,
        },
      ).toString();

      bool response = await Session.apiGet(url);
      if (response.runtimeType == ErrorModel) throw response;

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      print("Unable to check for updated theme: $error");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }
}

class LocaleHelpers {
  static final _directory = DIRECTORY_LOCALE;
  /// In order to support offline locale we ship the current version as at build
  /// time with the app.
  /// This method is to copy the files from the assets folder into the documents
  /// directory. This gives us the option to then update when needed.
  static copyLocaleFiles() async {
    String path = await FileHelpers.verifyOrCreateDirectory(_directory);

    for (var locale in globals.supportedLocale) {
      String localeKey = locale.toString();
      String localePath = '$path$localeKey.json';

      /// Check if the file already exists, if not copy it over
      if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(localePath) ==
          FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
        String assetPath = "assets/$_directory/$localeKey.json";
        String data = await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);

        FileHelpers.writeStringToFile(data, localePath);
      }
    }
  }

  static updateLocale() async {
    String path = await FileHelpers.verifyOrCreateDirectory(_directory);

    /// Iterate through locale and check each supported
    /// language if there is an updated version on the API
    for (Locale locale in globals.supportedLocale) {
      String localeString = locale.toString();
      var url = ApiEndpoint.uri('/locale/$localeString.json').toString();

      try {
        bool shouldUpdate = await _checkIfUpdated(localeString);
        if (shouldUpdate) {
          /// If Locale has been updated download the latest
          /// version and store it.
          ///
          /// Currently this happens as a non-blocking action
          /// so updates will take effect the next time the user opens the app.
          var response = await Session.apiGet(url);

          String localePath = '$path/$localeString.json';
          FileHelpers.writeStringToFile(localePath, jsonEncode(response));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print('Unable to update locale: $localeString');
      }
    }
  }

  /// This method makes  alight call comparing the [_sheetToFbDate] in our local
  /// copy of the Locale to the API version.
  static Future<bool> _checkIfUpdated(String langKey) async {
    try {
      String assetPath = '${globals.documentDirectory.path}/locale/$langKey.json';
      String data = await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);
      var currentLocaleDate = json.decode(data)['_sheetToFbDate'];

      var url = ApiEndpoint.uri(
        '/locale/check/$langKey',
        queryParameters: {
          "date": currentLocaleDate,
        },
      ).toString();
      bool response = await Session.apiGet(url);
      if (response.runtimeType == ErrorModel) throw response;

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      print("Unable to check for update: $langKey");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the debug console?

Comment: @aligator only when running the update method saying it's unable to load the file

Comment: I think that in android accessing the documents folder requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest. I'm sure that using the `getTemporaryDirectory` is going to solve this problem. but before changing it, try adding the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually realised that while not an issue on iOS, using `rootBundle.loadString` does not work for document storage on Android.

I needed to replace that bit with

```
File file = File('PATH_TO_FILE');
data = await file.readAsString();
```